# Does get() call in rule evaluation charge an extra read for every single document pulled down in a query through Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I went through the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) for Firestore pricing but was unable to find a clear answer to my question. Let's say I have a collection called posts and users pull down every document in the collection 'posts'. Now if the rule evaluation is such that

```
match /posts/{post} 
allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.hasSubscribed == true;
```

and the user pulls down 50 posts, will I be charged 50 additional reads (corresponding to the rule evaluation for every single document being requested in the query) because of the **get** call, making the total reads equal to 100 or will I be charged only 1 read for the entire query thus making the total number of reads equal to 51?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down to [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#firestore-rules) section, it says:

> You are only charged one read per dependent document even if your rules refer to that document more than once.

In your security you are accessing only 1 document `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));`. Even if you are fetching 50 documents, you are only charged once for that single document (for that request) i.e. costing you 51 reads.