# Firestore security rules functions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Does using get() inside security rules count as  document read ?

```
 match /Documents {
      function hasRole(role){        
        return request.auth != null && role in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles;
      }
      allow read: if 
        hasRole('admin') || 
        hasRole('user') || 
        hasRole('editor') || 
        hasRole('writer') 
    }
```

How can we improve the above code to get only one document read out of it ?

user profile is stored like this

```
/Users/user_id = {
   ...
   roles:['user','editor']
   ...
}
```

so far I managed to figure out that functions like `hasAll()`, `hasAny()`, `hasOnly()` can be used to test all roles in one go

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does get() call in rule evaluation charge an extra read for every single document pulled down in a query through Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916904/does-get-call-in-rule-evaluation-charge-an-extra-read-for-every-single-documen)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `get()`, `exists()`, and `getAfter()` inside Firestore Security rules gets counted under document reads and charged accordingly. You can go through [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#firestore-rules) to get a detailed explanation of the cost of using those methods inside Firestore Security rules.

Now to address your second question, by seeing the database structure from the Security rules you have provided, it seems it will read one document per request.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) will reduce to zero the number of reads for role based access control